# UK domestic partner squatting

Tags: united-kingdom, property

A couple have been together for a few decades.

One of them sold their house 10+ years ago when they hit hard times, since recovered from.

About 8 years ago the other inherited a house on their parents' death.

They are now living there with the non-owner paying no rent.

If the owner should die in future, could the non-owner claim some sort of squatter's rights and own the house?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No

But they can make a claim under the [Inheritance (Provision for Family and Dependants) Act 1975](https://www.teeslaw.com/article/legal-rights-unmarried-couples-living-together) if the deceased partner’s will makes inadequate provision for them or if there is no will.